# How do I style hyperlinks separately, using CSS?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I want to style different hyperlinks in different ways. Right now, I have a button that is a hyperlink, and I want to add a text that should act like a hyperlink too. How do I do this without styling both hyperlinks together. I want each hyperlink to have different colors, positioning etc.

**CSS**

```
.example2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CC4A31;
    color: #444;
    border-radius: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 38px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 145px;
    webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.example {
    color: black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example2"> 
    <a href="">GameTrade</a>
</div>

<div class="example">
    <a href="">Sign in</a>
</div>
```

Now how do I add another hyperlink, that is styled separately?

Comment: I don't understand. Is there a reason why you can't use different classes for different links?

Comment: I don't know how to do it!

Comment: If you don't know what classes are you probably should try reading through some css tutorials, they will help you in the long run: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp (CSS is pretty straight forward actually)

Comment: I suggest you do a little research, make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong. Look around in the "related" sidebar on the right side of this page for examples.

Comment: This post just looks like spam with that line right underneath the code. And the question is so basic that it seems to confirm it

Comment: I know what classes are, but it just doesn't seem to work for me to style different links. could someone just please write the code for doing it!?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you tried that doesn't seem to work. Without seeing what you tried, we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Here are some example CSS classes: .linkTypeOne{ color:blue;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;} .linkTypeTwo{ color:red;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal;}  .linkTypeTwo:hover {color: yellow};   you could then use them in your HTML like this:     <a class="linkTypeOne">Some Link</a>
    <a class="linkTypeTwo">Some Link2</a>

Comment: I will add the code that didn't work out for me!

Comment: I have updated the code. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @user3704821 your question is good as it was, considering what you seek, read bellow, for now that will point you on the right path, but some further reading as I suggest will be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call styles, is, in case you don't know also called CSS, which stands for Cascade Style Sheets, this type of language allows you among other things to specify an hierarchy between rules.

Having said this, in CSS you can have 3 basic types of style rules, the ones that target the TAG of elements, the ones that target the class of elements (`<a class="foo">my link</a>`) and the ones that target elements by ID (`<a id="btnSubmit">submit</a>`), I obviously hide much information here with the intent to make it simple for you to understand.

So to achieve your end, you can create a rule that targets elements with TAG `<a>`, and in rule you specify the properties that are generic to all links.

This gives you what you already have, now to target different links you have two options or you give then diferente IDs and you target each separately, or you add one class  to the class attribute so you can distinguish between both.

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<a class="link-trade1" href="">GameTrade 1</a><br/>
<a class="link-trade2" href="">GameTrade 2</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CC4A31;
    color: #444;
    border-radius: 9px;
    webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.link-trade1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 38px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 145px;
}

.link-trade2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px; /* other y position for the link 2 */
    left: 38px; /* other x position for the link 2 */
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 145px;
}
```

You can switch the class name for IDs if you don't intent to reuse the rules targeting that specific classes.

Anyway there is a very good [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596159900) you can read, if you are new to CSS and HTML, by Freeman.
Happy Coding.

**Update**

The updated question is a good example, just watch this:

```
/* this rule targets all hyperlinks inside, elements (div in your case) with attribute class="example" */
.example a{
    ... 
}

/* this rule targets all hyperlinks inside, elements with attribute class="example2" */
.example2 a{ 
    ... 
}
```

So as you can see, remember the hierarchy I was talking about? Is because of this, in the example just above you first target specific div's the ones with example class or example2 class and then you specify which elements to style inside them. You can build more elaborated rules!

Answer (score 1):

Using your HTML

```
<div class="example2"> 
    <a href="">GameTrade</a>
</div>

<div class="example">
    <a href="">Sign in</a>
</div>
```

I'm guessing the styling isn't working because there is CSS overriding yours. Try this CSS:

```
.example2 a {
    color: #444;
}

.example a {
    color: black;
}
```

If that doesn't work try adding !important tags.

Comment: Just a note, never use important annotations... They break CSS hierarchy, and mess further extensions to styles relying on CSS basic property which is inheritance.

Comment: !important tags should be avoided definitely, but there certainly are some occasions where they're useful. I definitely agree that as a general rule of practice they should be avoided.

Comment: but even for those special cases are techniques that you can explore, for instance, since CSS matches the longer rule always, and assuming that no one have messed with !importants before, you can pass over a rule (2) that is applied after your (1) by making you first rule longer or more specific, e.g: rule 1 "div a" rule 2 "div a", you can rewrite first rule as "html div a" to avoid using important.

Comment: One instance I can think of that they have been very useful for me is in testing. I'll occasionally add them when a line of CSS doesn't seem to be working. If adding them works then I know something else is conflicting with them, which I can then remove them and change my code. I agree that it is definitely best practice to add more specific code too and avoid the use of !important tags - it's a nightmare to work in someone else's code when they are in there - makes troubleshooting a huge hassle.

Comment: Yes for testing indeed, although doesn't save us always, I'm thinking about that case where some guy decided that <div style="font-size:9px!important;"></div>  was the right thing to do! :D